# Iterate through nested Dictionary Object and get the value of specific object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to get the value of all **ObjectId** from this Dictionary which is a combination of list and dictionary.
The required answer to me is
-> 2, 2, [[ "Value is 1"], ""], 3, 2

My solution to get the ObjectId. This was only giving me the value of inner ObjectId. Want to get the values of all ObjectId whether the value is int or list etc.

```
for key in dictObj:
    if key == "RESULT":
        if (type(dictObj[key])== list):
            for list in dictObj[key]:
                for key,value in list.items():
                    while(True):
                        if (type(value)==dict) and value:
                            for key1,value1 in value.items():
                                value = value1
                                key = key1
                        elif (key=="ObjectId"):
                            print(value)
                            break
                        else:
                            break
```

Dictionary Object is

```
dictObj =  {
            "Id": 1,
            "RESULT": [
                {
                    "Check": {
                        "checkinstance": {
                            "ObjectId": 2,
                            "Class": "Base"
                        }
                    },
                    "Class": "Base"
                },
                {
                    "ObjectId": 2,
                    "Class": "Base",
                    "Start": {}
                },
                {
                    "Display": {
                        "part": {
                            "Class": "Base",
                            "ObjectId": [
                                [
                                    "Value is 1"
                                ],
                                ""
                            ]
                        },
                        "load": {
                            "ObjectId": 3,
                            "Class": "Base"
                        }
                    },
                    "Class": "Base"
                },
                {
                    "ObjectId": 2,
                    "Class": "Base",
                    "Stop": {}
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I am not sure about my code so not adding that waiting for a solution

Comment: No, that's not how stack overflow works. You *should* add your non-working code so we can see what specific problem you are having. Note that this site is not for you to get answers, but instead for the millions of future programmers who encounter the same problem as you have.

Comment: `JSON` is a *string* representation of an object. What you have appears to be an actual object, specifically a dictionary and not `JSON`. If that's correct, you should edit your question to remove the `json` tag and the word `JSON` from the question. But since you haven't shown your code, that's a determination only you can make..

Comment: Added my code for review

Comment: `jsonObj` is definitely *not* a string and definitely *not* `JSON`; it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This code makes no assumption of the structure of the input object, `obj` (it can be a dictionary or list):

```
obj   = {
            "Id": 1,
            "RESULT": [
                {
                    "Check": {
                        "checkinstance": {
                            "ObjectId": 2,
                            "Class": "Base"
                        }
                    },
                    "Class": "Base"
                },
                {
                    "ObjectId": 2,
                    "Class": "Base",
                    "Start": {}
                },
                {
                    "Display": {
                        "part": {
                            "Class": "Base",
                            "ObjectId": [
                                [
                                    "Value is 1"
                                ],
                                ""
                            ]
                        },
                        "load": {
                            "ObjectId": 3,
                            "Class": "Base"
                        }
                    },
                    "Class": "Base"
                },
                {
                    "ObjectId": 2,
                    "Class": "Base",
                    "Stop": {}
                }
            ]
        }

def filter(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            filter(item)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        if "ObjectId" in obj:
            print(obj["ObjectId"])
        for v in obj.values():
            if isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
                filter(v)

filter(obj)
```

Prints:

```
2
2
[['Value is 1'], '']
3
2
```

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/sHxjC9)

If you don't want to print the values but instead accumulate them into a list then:

```
def filter2(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            yield from filter2(item)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        if "ObjectId" in obj:
            yield obj["ObjectId"]
        for v in obj.values():
            if isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
                yield from filter2(v)

print(list(filter2(obj)))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 2, [['Value is 1'], ''], 3, 2]
```

[Pyhon Demo](https://ideone.com/08naei)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a recursive function which searches all keys in a `dict` and then all the keys of the values which are also `dict`s:

```
# dictObj as in post

def findKey(key, d, result):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k == key:
            result.append(v)
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            findKey(key, v, result)



result = []

for key in dictObj:
    if key == "RESULT":
        if (type(jsonObj[key])== list):
            for d in jsonObj[key]:
                findKey('ObjectId', d, result)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, [[ "Value is 1"], ""], 3, 2]
```